# Should polyurethane sheet seams be taped?

Tags: insulation

I am going to place PUR insulation plates, the dealer recommends that each joint should be sealed off with aluminum tape, but could not say what the advantages are of doing this?

Can someone please explain? I don't like to do something just because someone said so, but cannot explain why..

Image of the insulation type
PUR = PolyUrethane
[image]

Comment: Are they flooring underlayment, or what?

Comment: In this case no, it's for walls.